# CMake: C++ linting not recognising include directory

Tags: c++, cmake, neovim, lint, clangd

I am very new to CMake and I am trying to setup my C++ project workspace so that all of the ".h" files are in a "includes" directory while all of the ".cpp" files are in the "sources" directory. The file tree looks something like this:

```
.
└── project/
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── includes/
    │   ├── test.h
    │   └── ...
    └── sources/
        ├── test.cpp
        └── ...
```

My goal is that I would like to be able to call `#include "test.h"` directly in `main.cpp` without the need of having to give it the relative path, i.e. avoid having to write `#include "includes/test.h"`. The relevant files are as follows:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(MyProject)

# Set C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

# Include directories
set( INCLUDE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes" )
include_directories(${INCLUDE_PATH})

# Source files
file(GLOB SOURCES "sources/*.cpp")

# Create executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

int main(){
    messenger::print_header();
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "test.h"

void messenger::print_header(){
    std::cout << "INSIDE HEADER" << std::endl;

}
```

**test.h**

```
namespace messenger {
    void print_header();
}
```

This combination compiles fine and I can run the program but my lsp still complains that the `test.h` file is not being found. This error appears in both `main.cpp` and `test.cpp` when I use just `#include "test.h"`

[image: main.cpp]

[image: test.cpp]

The warnings nicely disappear when I switch to relative paths to the `includes directory`.

[image: main.cpp (no errors)]

[image: test.cpp (no errors)]

I am using the clangd lsp installed using the [mason-lspconfig](https://github.com/williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim) package for neovim. Is this a problem with the configuration for the lsp or a CMake issue?

Comment: `file(GLOB SOURCES "sources/*.cpp")` is bad. If you add a new .cpp fries, the globber will not catch it until you reconfigure cmake.

Comment: `#include "test.h"` should work with CMake. I know nothing of lsp.

Comment: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9fn8PfGn8), it actually works just that globber didn't catched it until you reconfigure. You should use the [CONFIGURE_DEPENDS](https://godbolt.org/z/9fn8PfGn8) flag to retrigger globber whenever you build.

Comment: Are you running cmake with `-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1` as documented at https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup?

Comment: It's not a CMake problem but a LSP/Linter/clangd configuration problem. Do you have a [compile_commands.json](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) in the right place? There are several questions and answers on getting clangd to work with either editor on this site.

Comment: Another thing, if you're just starting out with CMake, you might spend some time getting to know *best practices* as opposed to the collection of anti-patterns in your setup. Call your dirs `src` and `include/your_project`. Don't glob source files, prefer CMake's `target_*` commands, i.e. `target_include_directories` over `include_directories`. Don't create superfluous CMake variables. None of these is a big problem but you could just as easily have a very nice project.